# How to use a filepath as input to find if a file or directory exists in Bash

Tags: bash

I don't understand how to use the paths in the examples.

For example

when I am checking if a file/directory exists I would do some variation of

```
if test (-e or -a or -f or -d)$2; then
    echo y
else
    echo n
fi
```

then I would do finddir.sh acb /testdir

and it would echo n. However, when I do the same thing without the first slash (testdir) it works, so I tried to cut off the first slash using

```
PATH=$2
PATH=$(PATH:1)
```

Then replaced $2 in the first code with $PATH  (It echos the path without the first slash (tested with echo)), but that didn't work either

Also if I put a path longer than a single directory (/testdir/testdir2) it doesn't work either

I tried other changes like testing with [[]] or [] but nothing helped

For the findfile.sh, where I had to find if a file exists using a path, I tried using the first code and it was able to find the file using just the plain file name while it the same directory as the file (i.e. ./findfile.sh abc /samp.tar), which didn't work, but did work when removing the slash again. However, whenever I put anything else (/testdir/testdir2/samp.tar) it does not work.

Comment: Use ${VAR:1} with {}, not (). And maybe choose a different local variable name than PATH.

Comment: I am a bit confused about using $2 and never $1 in your script

Comment: A slash at the beginning of a path indicates that the path is "absolute", meaning that it starts at the root of the filesystem. It appears you are using a "relative" path (one that starts in the current working directory), in which case it should have a slash at the beginning. So don't put the slash there in the first place.